# Why there is no improvement in inference-time/size when YOLOv4 is transformed with TensorFlow Lite? Are there any possible improvements?

Tags: python, tensorflow, yolo

I'm currently working with YOLOv4 and [COCO](https://cocodataset.org/#home) dataset. I'm creating the model directly from the weights (you can download them [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cewMfusmPjYWbrnuJRuKhPMwRe_b9PaT/view)) and then transforming it to TensorFlow Lite format with the next parameters:

```py
model = load_yolo(weights)  # Function to create the yolo model & load the weights
tflite_converter = tflite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model)
tflite_model = tflite_converter.convert()
```

My main goal is to get a faster YOLOv4 model (and hopefully smaller). Currently, I'm executing the model on my laptop and it takes between 3 and 4 seconds to run inference on a single image (608x608x3). That is the reason why I decided to transform the model to TensorFlow Lite format. However, I'm getting very similar results time-wise (it also takes between 3 and 4 seconds to run inference on a single image with the model transformed to TensorFlow Lite format). Furthermore, the resulting *.tflite* file is more or less of the same size than the weights file (~250MB). In addition, when quantizing the model (`tflite_converter.optimizations = [tflite.Optimize.DEFAULT]`) I get even worse results timewise (the .tflite file is ~4x smaller though).

Even thought TensorFlow Lite is said to be optimized for [edge devices](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/performance/model_optimization), when transforming a model with this tool in my laptop (Windows 10 OS), I used to always get faster (and smaller) models. That is why I decided to take this approach with YOLOv4. Is there a reason for getting these 'bad performance' results with the YOLOv4 model? Is this a good approach to get a faster version of YOLOv4? And, are there any other options or better approaches to get a faster version of YOLOv4 (like [YOLOv4-tiny](https://models.roboflow.com/object-detection/yolov4-tiny-darknet))?

NOTE: I'm using TensorFlow 2.4.1.

EDIT: When testing TensorFlow Lite with different models, the deeper the model, the lower is its performance compared to normal TensorFlow. It depends on the hardware, but TensorFlow Lite may not be the best option for improving the performance of big models.

Comment: You can try `float16` or `int16` quantization. See [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/performance/post_training_quantization). For Android devices, we can utilize the GPU ( of the mobile device ) for inference, using the [GpuDelegate](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/performance/gpu)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have just tried float16 quantization, but I got no improvement.

Comment: Did you try `int16` quantization?

Comment: Yes, but the inference time got even worse.